# Show images added as items when using subitems added as tree nodes in a listview

Tags: c#, listview, treenode, imagelist

I have spent a great deal of time trying to implement image previews in a listview. The best i can achieve is the same image repeated for each item in the listview as the below code will just add the first image from the listviewimages() method. I tried using an index and I get an error such as can't add item twice remove the first instance. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{

        //
        ImageList imageList1 = new ImageList();
        imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(32, 32);
        listView_Families.LargeImageList = listViewImages();

        TreeNode newSelected = e.Node;
        listView_Families.Items.Clear();
        DirectoryInfo nodeDirInfo = (DirectoryInfo)newSelected.Tag;
        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] subItems;
        ListViewItem item = null;

            //If selected is a directory show the following
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in nodeDirInfo.GetDirectories())
            {

                item = new ListViewItem(dir.Name, 0);

                subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
                    {new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "Directory"), 
                     new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item,
                                      dir.LastWriteTime.ToShortTimeString())};


                item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
                listView_Families.Items.Add(item);
            }


            //If selected is a File show the following
            foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                string fileFullName = file.FullName;


                item = new ListViewItem(file.Name, 1);

                subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
                {
                  new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, file.FullName), 
                  new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, file.Length.ToString())     
                };

                item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);

                //add items to list view
                listView_Families.Items.Add(item);


            }//end loop


        listView_Families.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You never set the `ListViewItem.ImageIndex` so it is always 0 and therefore only the 1st image is shown.

You should determine which image you want to show for each item and set the right index!

The `LargeImageList` is only **loosely associated** with the `ListView`. To actually connect its `Images` with the `Items` you need to set the `Items.ImageIndex` of each `Item`! This way you can re-use the Images for many Items and also freely change the ImageIndex of an Item..

From your code I don't know how you want to decide which is the right image..